# jQuery validation - validate sections as well as globally in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, jquery-validate

I have a page similar to the below given diagram,

[image]

The page has multiple sections (User Information, Account Information etc;) as well as common controls (like subject textbox, date textbox etc)

- When the user clicks on Add button in user information section, it has to validate the associated controls
- When the user clicks on the Submit button in the top, the subject textbox and the table should be validated for required data.

How can I achieve this?

I am able to validate the user section but not sure how to proceed with global validation on the page.

**TypeScript:**

```
class Validation {

    static FormTrackingId = '#FormTracking';

    private static ApplyRules() {

        $(Component.SelectId).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Name is required."
            }
        });

        $(Component.TextBoxNumberId).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Number is required."
            }
        });

        $(Component.TextAreaNotesId).rules("add", {
            maxlength: 10,
            messages: {
                maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("The maximum allowed length of note(s) is {0} characters.")
            }
        });
    }

    public static IsValid(): boolean{

        $(Validation.FormTrackingId).validate();

        Validation.ApplyRules();

        return $(Validation.FormTrackingId).valid();
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on how to handle this scenario will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're talking about.  What is the HTML structure?  Is there a `<form></form>` nested within a `<form></form>`?  If so, that's invalid HTML and the jQuery Validate plugin will not work.